# Failed to resolve import ScrollSmoother

Tags: reactjs, gsap, vite

It says it failed to resolve import ScrollSmoother

thats my code :

```
import gsap from "gsap"
import ScrollTrigger from 'gsap/ScrollTrigger';
import ScrollSmoother  from "gsap/ScrollSmoother";


gsap.registerPlugin(ScrollTrigger,ScrollSmoother) <-------

const Navbar = () => {

      return (
      <div>Hello world</div>
    )
  }
  
  export default Navbar
```

thats what shows on my screen
[image]

PS: iam using vite

Comment: ScrollSmoother is a plugin that's exclusive to Club Greensock members. It does not automatically install when performing the usual `npm install gsap` Look [at the install helper here](https://greensock.com/docs/v3/Installation?checked=core,scrollTrigger,scrollSmoother#modules). Did you purchase a membership, and follow the instructions to run and install that specific module?

Comment: i thought that scrollSmoother was build on top of scrollTrigger but thank you , now i understand

Answer (score 0):

Please note that while you can use this CDN for trial purposes on your test projects, it's crucial not to deploy it in production. This CDN is intended for testing purposes only.

"https://assets.codepen.io/16327/ScrollSmoother.min.js"

Alternatively, you can use the following command to install the trial package using npm:

npm install gsap-trial

For more information about trial packages, you can visit the official GSAP documentation page at the following link: [GSAP Installation Documentation](https://gsap.com/docs/v3/Installation/?checked=core,scrollTrigger,scrollSmoother#modules)